# How to use Test data on saved model with queue approach (without feed_dict) #tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

I am new to tensorflow. I have build a convonet for mnist image classification as follows I am using queues to read images(png) from the disk batch it and pass it to train op (I am quite comfortable with this now) It's all good till train and I am evaluating my accuracy op at certain number of steps while training.

I am saving the model with Saver object and can see the meta and checkpoint file being written on the disk.

Now the real challenge is to restore the model once it has finished training and use it for predictions on new images

One of the first step in my graph (to train) is like below which takes x_image (images from train queue) h_conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(x_image, W_conv1) + b_conv1)

As I am not using feed dictionary approach, I can not just restore the accuracy op using saver and pass the new data. I have to define the queue for test data and rebuild the graph (exactly as earlier) with reference x_image changed to point to test data Queue.

How can I now restore the learned weights while training and use it to with this new graph to simply run my predict/accuracy op.

I tried to follow 
 - https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/image/cifar10/cifar10.py tutorial but got lost with eval code.

Also if I add a dummy constant in my training graph and then try to retrive it's value, I am able to retrive it.

Can any 1 please help. Thanks

Comment: I am able to use saver.restore() and restore the variables of the graph.
Cautiously I am not running tf.global_variables_initializer() so that the variables/weights are not re-initialized but gets restored from the saved model.

The only strange thing I am observing now is that my predict op returns different label for the same input image. I am using tf.train.shuffle_batch() to generate test sample. Can any point out my mistake.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

OK, So I have found the answer.

The original challenge was to to toggle between train and test data while training and validation phase when using queues.
Now as queues are part of graph structure, we can't simply modify them.

I found an article to use tf.case to toggle between train and test queue but I wasn't able to use shuffle batch along with it.

The real task at hand was to save the model post training and use the saved model to predict in production.

So here is the flow:

**Training**

- create a method that creates your graph (will take image tensor as
  input).
- Build a training graph by passing training image batches
- Perform training and save the model with saver object.

**Evaluation**

- Now reconstruct the same graph with test image batches.
- In the session use saver object to restore the weights (Note you dont need to pass which variables to restore, by default it restores all restore able variables)
  **Dont run gloabl variable initializer at this time**
- Run your predict op (generated from the newly constructed graph)

**Also make sure you switch off the drop out functionality in the eval as it would keep varying the output for the same input**

Below is the pseudocode

```
train_op, y_predict, accuracy = create_graph(train_input, train_label)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)
    model_saver = tf.train.Saver()

    for i in range(2000):
        if i%100 == 0:
           train_accuracy = sess.run(accuracy)
           print("step %d, training accuracy %f" %(i, train_accuracy))
        sess.run(train_op)

    print(sess.run(accuracy))
    model_saver.save(sess, 'model/simple_model', global_step=100)
    coord.request_stop()
    coord.join(threads)
```

---

For evaluation

```
_, y_predict, accuracy = create_graph(test_input, test_label)

saver = tf.train.Saver()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint("./model/"))

    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)
    label_predict = sess.run([y_predict])
```